# ¿Como puedo hacer para que el .split() funcione en todas las palabras que componen la variable?

Tags: javascript

necesito que el algoritmo se ejecute en ambas palabras de la variable (solo se ejecuta en una, y si lequitas la otra palabra y los corchetes) y que dichas palabras se vean por separado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="alf"></h3>

</body>
<script>
var palabras = ["hola", "maria"];
var alfa = palabras.split("");


alfa.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });


document.getElementById("alf").innerHTML = alfa;


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres obtener, un array de arrays, como `[ ['h','o','l','a'],['m','a','r','i','a']]`?

Comment: si, esa es la idea

Comment: la función `split()` es para las variables de tipo String, ahi estas intentando aplicarla a un Array, tendrias que tomar el valor al interno del array .. te aconsejo que mires [este sitio en inglés](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) en el cual podes encontrar buen material sobre Javascript :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu variable `palabras` es un array por lo que tiene que recorrerlo para aplicar la función a todos sus elementos. Tienes varias formas de hacerlo. La más sencilla es con un `for` que recorra tu `array` (mientras añades en otro `array` los valores del `split`):

```js
var palabras = ["hola", "maria"];
var alfa=[];

for(let i=0;i<palabras.length;i++){
  alfa.push(palabras[i].split(""));
}

for(let i=0;i<alfa.length;i++){
  alfa[i].sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });
  console.log(alfa[i].join(','));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="alf"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

También puedes utilizar [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) y/o [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach):

```js
var palabras = ["hola", "maria"];
var alfa=palabras.map(function(p){
  return p.split("");
});

alfa.forEach(function(p,i){
  p.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });
  console.log(p.join(','));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="alf"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución sencilla sería usar `map()` y luego (opcionalmente, si quieres todas la letras en un único array) `flat()`:

```js
let palabras = ["hola", "maria"];
let palabrasSeparadas = palabras.map(p => p.split(''));
console.log(palabrasSeparadas);

let letras = palabrasSeparadas.flat().sort();
console.log(letras);
```